# Insert data in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to add data in single table using a SQL Server stored procedure and I am getting an error

> procedure or function x has too many argument specified

Also how can I get newly created ID of record as I need to update multiple tables using these IDs

I am using SQL Server 2012

Many thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateNewFunctionsNavigation]
   @FunctionName nvarchar(250),
   @Hierarchy_Level int
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT [dbo].[Navigation_Functions] ([FunctionName], [Hierarchy_Level])
   VALUES(@FunctionName, @Hierarchy_Level)
END
```

Execution of stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CreateNewFunctionsNavigation]
        @FunctionName = N'DSD',
        @Hierarchy_Level = 3

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

My SQL for Function table

```
USE [MySolution01_DB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Navigation_Functions]    Script Date: 06/01/2015 15:58:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Navigation_Functions](
 [Function_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FunctionName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 [Hierarchy_Level] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Functions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Function_ID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

  GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_Functions] ([FunctionName], [Hierarchy_Level])
```

I created a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Navigation_Functions](
    [NavigationFunctionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FunctionName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Hierarchy_Level] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Navigation_Functions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [NavigationFunctionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What's your table structure look like? Is your primary key column set to be the primary key? Is it an int type? If so, do you have Is Identity set to Yes under Identity Specification?

Comment: I added a sample script of the table creation.

Comment: yes I have primary key FunctionID whose Identity set to yes

Comment: i have updated my question with SQL Script for my table

Comment: Everything you posted worked for me in SQL Management Studio. I used it verbatim. Are you calling this from some other place like a web application?

Comment: no I am also using SQL Server Management Studio ... I am getting result so I take this good to go, hope its not going to break later on. I have also given answer up.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last ID by: `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [MySolution01_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateNewFunctionsNavigation]
  @FunctionName nvarchar(250),
  @Hierarchy_Level INT,
  @Function_identity INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_Functions] ([FunctionName],[Hierarchy_Level] ) 
VALUES(@FunctionName, @Hierarchy_Level);

   SET @Function_identity=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   RETURN @Function_identity

RETURN
END
```